# Alternate URI with Azure Mobile Client SDK

Tags: azure, mobile, xamarin

When using Azure Mobile Client SDK, apart from the web URL, there seems to be no control over the URL of the REST end point that will be hit.  By default, the request will go to (GET) **www.myurl.com/tables/entity** to return all entities.  What can I do to inject a version number between **tables** and **entity**, such as **/tables/v1/entity**?  I know that I could do **www.myurl.com/v1/tables/entity** but that's not the solution I am looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: The MobileClient is made to specifically talk to the Azure mobile services backend. If you are using it for a custom backend, you propably have to fork from their source.

Answer (score 0):

From my test, we could use attribute to achieve this scenario. Here are the steps:

1) Add config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes in startup file

```html
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);
```

2) Add attribute Route in the method that you want to custom the domain.

```html
   [Route("tables/v1/todoitem")]
        // GET tables/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
            return Query();
        }
```

The following is the result on my local:

[image]

Hope this could give you some tips.